# Android app no longer linking to existing firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Using android studio, I created an app and linked it to a Firebase project.

I opened the app on my android studio recently and discovered it wasn't linked to my Firebase project any longer. I checked the Firebase console and saw that the app was still connected. However, it's still not reflecting in my android studio.

When I try to connect my app to Firebase (afresh), I can clearly see my Firebase project as one of the options (with one app connected ==> my app).

In summary, how do I reconnect an app to firebase?

I have tried restarting my android studio, cleaning the project, invalidating cache and restarting.

Comment: google recently sent out an e-mail saying that if you don't add a billing account to firebase (even if you are using free firebase projects) that they projects will be deactivated. did you check this?

Comment: *firebaser here* @Photogd I don't recall seeing such a message anywhere, and would be highly surprised. Can you give an exact quote from the message you refer to, to see if I missed something or if it's a matter of misinterpretation?

Comment: I don't recall seeing or hearing that anywhere either. If it were true (and truly a recent development), it would have been mentioned at I/O. Probably a rumour.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I got it like 2 weeks ago, this is what it said:

We would like to highlight a few updates that may impact your implementation. Beginning June 11th, we are launching our new pricing plan and providing all users access to support. We’ll continue to offer a free tier — all developers will receive $200 of free monthly usage of our core products.

In addition, this change will require you to enable billing and associate it with all of your projects.

Comment: Hmmm... I honestly have never seen that email and it sounds extremely unlike Firebase. The free tier is not going anywhere. I hope it's just some context that is missing in the quote. Can you forward the complete message to me on "puf (at) firebase (dot) com" so I can figure out what it is?

Comment: @Photogd All I could find was: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html That was an update from the Google Maps platform, which is unrelated to Firebase's free tier.

Comment: Downvoting is cool, not stating why isn't.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is no **external tampering** with an android studio project, an android app would always remain connected to Firebase.

I was able to solve this problem by signing out of all my Google accounts and then signing in with the account associated with the project. All I had to do after was attempt to reconnect again and *kAbOoM*, it worked fine.

There are two extra checkers/fixes I'd recommend to anyone that runs into this problem:

1. Check whether the google-services.json file exists. It's usually in the `/app` directory of android projects. If this file does not exist, it means the app is not connected to any Firebase project. One can then proceed to connect one's app to Firebase either manually or on the android-studio IDE. If the file exists, proceed to 2.
2. Dependencies: A lot of Firebase-type problems stem from dependency issues. Ensure the following:

- Avoid version conflicts
- Ensure that all dependencies are up-to-date
- Take warnings seriously, they are like seedling-errors

I hope this helps other people who might run into this error.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting such kind of error at firebase integration you have to do following steps to link your playstore app to firebase.

1. Select your project com.android.app.
2. Select the project setting.
3. Select users and permissions. Add member who have published the target app.
4. Finally, you will see the link play store button under the integration tab.